# Can a Django form field be rendered without a Django form?

Tags: django

I have a simple HTML form for which I was not using a Django form, but now I want to add a select.

The select would be most easily created as a Django `ChoiceField` (as opposed to creating the select manually by looping, etc), however, it seems that it won't render properly without being bound/created within a Django form. (By not rendering properly, the browser shows `<django.forms.widgets.Select object at 0x10e9a9d10>`)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why not just use a django form?.. You should also explain what you mean about it not rendering properly (errors?)

Comment: Added comment about the rendering. Interested in knowing if this is possible because it seems like it could/should be possible, and it would potentially be a simpler change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use Django Form. But if you really don't want to use the form. You can generate HTML from ChoiceField in your view and pass the html to your template.

```
from django.forms import fields
my_choice = fields.ChoiceField(choices=((1, '1'), (2,'2')))
field_name = 'my_choice'
field_value = 1
my_choice_html = my_choice.widget.render(field_name, field_value)
return render(request, 'template.html', {'my_choice': my_choice_html})
```